# Two paragraphs changing positions inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

Hi! I am trying to place two paragraphs inside a DIV (a Name and a Job Position) for a responsive site.

```css
.header {
  min-height: 56px;
  transition: min-height 0.3s;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.header__inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  display: inline;
}

.header__text {
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <img class="header__logo" src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="header__text">
      <p class="header__title">
        NAME
      </p>
      <p class="header__subtitle">
        CURRENT POSITION
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Whenever I start playing with different sizes of screen both paragraphs switch places randomly. How can I make sure that they will stay in order?

This is how the page looks 
[Page with misplaced texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5CLE.png)

And this is what I would like to accomplish

[what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GrSm.png)

Comment: Use flexbox instead of floats, it will make your life a lot easier (and you also get the added bonus of flex ordering, meaning you can do neat things like change the order of your divs on mobile versus desktop).

Comment: `both paragraphs switch places randomly.` how ? i don't see this

Comment: "Whenever I start playing with different sizes of screen both paragraphs switch places randomly". What sizes are you playing with that caused the effect as you stated?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've added some images showing my problem.

Comment: Avoid totally floats. This is really easy to achieve with  `display: inline-block ; text-align: right;` on parent.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't post the CSS for the two elements whose position you want to switch, `header__title` and `header__subtitle`. But apparently they are both floated right. To make sure `header__subtitle` is NOT displayed to the left of `header__title` even if there is enough space, you can add this:

```
.header__subtitle {
  clear: right;
}
```